# How can you tell if a MagicalRecord operation was successful?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I make heavy use of MagicalRecord for fetching, deleting, updating and saving data.  I have noticed in testing that I don't get expected results because something went wrong with the operation I was attempting, such as a bad predicate resulting in no record being updated or deleted, etc.

I have looked at the available docs (such as they are) and can find nothing that give a method for examining any return code, etc.

Anyone know of a place that lists *all* of the available MR methods *with explanations* (other than the MR Categories and Core)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what it is you're looking for in the way of documentation. The primary reason for sparse documentation for the project is that the core data docs cover the vast majority of the features. Magical record is merely a set of convenience methods that make standard operations in core data much more manageable.

The parts that are 'non standard' core data functionality may need some extra explanation in how things work, but they source is also available to read and understand. If you have a specific question, please ask it.

Comment: I didn't even think of that... was thinking MR interfaced with SQLite, not CoreData.  Thank you...